# flutter Erorr I cant deal with

Tags: flutter

I tried making a class then making a list of that class and I get an Erorr

```
the class I created:



class Transaction {

  final String id;
  final String title;
  final double amount;
  final DateTime date;

  Transaction({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.amount,
    required this.date,
  });
}
```

Erorrs I get :
[image]

Comment: `final List<Transaction> Transaction = [...]` is wrong. First import the Transaction class and then you can't define the list with the same name as that of the class. So, you can do : `final List<Transaction> transactions = [...]`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your variable name as it is clashing with the class name `Transaction`
and you can also use a different approach:

```
final List<Transaction>? transactionList;
trnasactionList.add(Transaction(id:1,title:'flutter' ....));
trnasactionList.add(Transaction(id:2,title:'flutter' ....));
```